# Format string in python list

Tags: python

I have a list which should contain string with a particular format or character i.e. `{{str(x), str(y)},{str(x), str(y)}}`. I tried to do string concat like: `"{{"+str(x), str(y)+"},{"+str(x), str(y)+"}}"` and append to list, but it gets surrounded by brackets: [`({{str(x), str(y)}),({str(x), str(y)}})`]
How can I get rid of the brackets or betterstill, is there a better approach to having a list without brackets like this: `[{{string, string},{string, string}}]`

Comment: Those braces; you heard about sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are because you're creating a tuple of three items:

- `"{{"+str(x)`
- `str(y)+"},{"+str(x)`
- `str(y)+"}}"`

Try replacing those bare commas between `str(x)` and `str(y)` with `+","+`:

```
"{{"+str(x)+","+str(y)+"},{"+str(x)+","str(y)+"}}"
```